# How to create Agent and migrate it to Remot host?

Tags: java, agents-jade, taglet

I am looking to create Multi-agent systems based focused crawling. I have seen different mobile framworks such as Aglet, JADE, etc,. My work is want to create a number of agent at resident Local host and want to move it with parameter to resident Remote host. My question are, which framwork should I used to create agent? and how to create agent and migrate it to remote host via middle agent. please give me some example code how to create agent and migrate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Mobility-RPC](http://code.google.com/p/mobility-rpc/), there are examples to do this on the front page.